Как отправить сообщение пользователю в pyrogram
У меня есть список chat.id пользователей, которые запускали бота. Мне нужно им написать сообщение от имени бота, а не пользователя. В модуле telebot всё работает
import telebot
bot=telebot.TeleBot(Token)
users=[93028429,429842402,29092348]
for i in users:
     bot.send_message(i, 'Hello!')

Как реализовать то же самое используя pyrogram?
